# How to handle non consistent rows using CSVHelper using ClassMap?

Tags: csvhelper

I am having issues defining ClassMap for csv file given below, which has non consistent rows.

```
trip_id,arrival_time,departure_time,stop_id,stop_sequence,stop_headsign,pickup_type,drop_off_time,shape_dist_traveled

STBA,6:00:00,6:00:00,STAGECOACH,1,,,,

AB2,12:15:00,12:15:00,BEATTY_AIRPORT,2
```

```
        {
            Map(m => m.TripId).Name("trip_id");
            Map(m => m.ArrivalTime).Name("arrival_time").Optional();
            Map(m => m.DepartureTime).Name("departure_time").Optional();
            Map(m => m.StopId).Name("stop_id");
            Map(m => m.StopSequence).Name("stop_sequence");
            Map(m => m.StopHeadsign).Name("stop_headsign").Optional();
            Map(m => m.PickupType).Name("pickup_type").Optional();
            Map(m => m.DropOffType).Name("drop_off_type").Optional();
            Map(m => m.ContinuousPickup).Name("continuous_pickup").Optional();
            Map(m => m.ContinuousDropOff).Name("continuous_drop_off").Optional();
            Map(m => m.ShapeDistTraveled).Name("shape_dist_traveled").Optional();
            Map(m => m.Timepoint).Name("timepoint").Optional();
        }
```

Although StopHeadsign is optional, reading second row fails because header is present, so it expects field to be present. Error is field at index does not exist. Setting default value is also not possible because field does not exist. How do I make it truly optional?

Thanks

Comment: `config.MissingFieldFound = Nothing, config.TrimOptions = True` ? I will also recommend building a short [mre]: A classe with 3 properties and csv line that illustrate exactly you edge case. For default value they can be set in the object declaration directly. It's unclear if the blank line are real in the CSV. It's also unclear if you clss is define with nullable type.

Comment: Here is a base  MRE of how it works https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q86rMa

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `Optional` basically means it's optional if you include the field in the header.  I don't believe that what you have would be considered valid CSV.  However, as @DragandDrop [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75510255/how-to-handle-non-consistent-rows-using-csvhelper-using-classmap/75513018#comment133225457_75510255), you can set `MissingFieldFound = null` and ignore the `MissingFieldException`.

```cs
void Main()
{
    
    var input = new StringBuilder();
    input.AppendLine("trip_id,arrival_time,departure_time,stop_id,stop_sequence,stop_headsign,pickup_type,drop_off_time,shape_dist_traveled");
    input.AppendLine("STBA,6:00:00,6:00:00,STAGECOACH,1,,,,");
    input.AppendLine("AB2,12:15:00,12:15:00,BEATTY_AIRPORT,2");
    
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        MissingFieldFound = null
    };
    
    using (var reader = new StringReader(input.ToString()))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<FooMap>();
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList().Dump();
    }
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.TripId).Name("trip_id");
        Map(m => m.ArrivalTime).Name("arrival_time").Optional();
        Map(m => m.DepartureTime).Name("departure_time").Optional();
        Map(m => m.StopId).Name("stop_id");
        Map(m => m.StopSequence).Name("stop_sequence");
        Map(m => m.StopHeadsign).Name("stop_headsign").Optional();
        Map(m => m.PickupType).Name("pickup_type").Optional();
        Map(m => m.DropOffType).Name("drop_off_type").Optional();
        Map(m => m.ContinuousPickup).Name("continuous_pickup").Optional();
        Map(m => m.ContinuousDropOff).Name("continuous_drop_off").Optional();
        Map(m => m.ShapeDistTraveled).Name("shape_dist_traveled").Optional();
        Map(m => m.Timepoint).Name("timepoint").Optional();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string TripId { get; set; }
    public string ArrivalTime { get; set; }
    public string DepartureTime { get; set; }
    public string StopId { get; set; }
    public string StopSequence { get; set; }
    public string StopHeadsign { get; set; }
    public string PickupType { get; set; }
    public string DropOffType { get; set; }
    public string ContinuousPickup { get; set; }
    public string ContinuousDropOff { get; set; }
    public string ShapeDistTraveled { get; set; }
    public string Timepoint { get; set; }
}
```